# how to using resources in entity frame work core for making Multilanguage Application?

Tags: entity-framework-core, multilingual, data-annotations, ef-fluent-api, asp.net-core-5.0

Hope have a nice day .

I want to make a Multilanguage Application in .net core 5 .

we have resources and using DisplayName attribute in viewModel base application .
But how we can create Multilanguage Application or using resources in EfCore?

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mre] .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution.

I was working on a **Code-First** Application which deployed using **Fluent** and I wanted to implement Validation error messages in Other Language.

I did This steps:

1- Create .resx files for messages and property names .

2- I used FluentValidation Library :

https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/index.html

3- I passed The Persian error using Errors.resx and pass the property name using Names.resx

RuleFor(c => c.EndDate).MaximumLength(10).WithMessage(Errors.MaxLength).WithName(Names.EndDate);

Errors.MaxLength is from Errors.resx and Names.EnDate is from Names.resx

Answer (score 0):

```
[Display(Name = "Email", ResourceType  = typeof(Resource))]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

Here, the typeof(Resource) is the file name for resources.

[image]

Comment: This way is usnig DataAnnotation and I use Fluent api in EFcore specially codeFirst Application , is it normal using both DataAnnotation and fluent api ?

Comment: It is recommended to using Fluent but if you use DataAnnotation for some stuff such as localization, it is ok.

Answer (score 0):

As another solution, you can add localization to your ASP.NET Core application using the recommended approach of providing resources for the default language as keys, and only adding additional resources as required later.

In summary, the steps to localize your application are rough as follows:

1. Add the required localization services
2. Configure the localization middleware and if necessary a culture
   provider
3. Inject IStringLocalizer into your controllers and services to
   localize strings
4. Inject IViewLocalizer into your views to localize strings in views
5. Add resource files for non-default cultures
6. Add a mechanism for users to choose their culture

Take a look at [this article](https://andrewlock.net/adding-localisation-to-an-asp-net-core-application/) for a detailed walkthrough.